# Tag synonym: cycle-computer --> bike-computer

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

We have 55 questions tagged [bike-computer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bike-computer) and another 13 tagged [cycle-computer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycle-computer). These should be synonymized.

(And, on meta, we have both "tagging" and "tags", which should probably also be synonymized!)

Comment: A meta-meta question on meta?  Is that a Para- question or a meta^2- question?

Comment: @Criggie Your question is off-topic here and should be asked at bicycles.meta.meta.meta.stackexchange.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Totally reasonable - go for it.

Comment: Somebody else will have to do it -- I don't have enough rep to propose synonyms.

Comment: You also need to have five accepted answers to questions in that tag, from memory.

Comment: Surprisingly, I do, so the tag synononom is made.  Its now awaiting 5 upvotes or 2 downvotes.

Comment: You only need 2500 rep to propose synonyms. The full list of things you get with rep is [in the help centre](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/) but the executive summary is that, with 21.6k rep, you have everything except access to the site analytics.

Comment: I used my mod powers to "approve" the tag synonym and also merge the tags.